# Using jQuery ajax to call Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Firstly let me preface this by saying I would never WANT to do this, nor do I intend to do this, I simply need to know if it is possible.

Considering that you can place "javascript:myFunction();" in a link's href attribute, is it possible to specify "javascript:myFunction();" as the url parameter in jQuery's $.ajax function?

Again, I know this would be counterintuitive and a pointless exercise for any production code. I am simply interested in whether it could theoretically be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not work.

The `javascript:myFunction()` is something of a hack URL that you can put as the `href` of an anchor to link to a JS function.

`$.ajax` wants to make an HTTP request and will attempt to, with whatever URL you provide. In the case of a `javascript:*` URL, it will do nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

You're free to pass that to "$.ajax()" as the URL, but it won't work. It's really an ugly old practice to use "javascript:" values for anchor tag "href" values too.

Answer (score 0):

No this will not work as intended. The A element is special case, and using that string with jQ.ajax() will result in a bad URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in the url but the "javascript:" will becomes part of url, so you may get error that the url path can't be found as when browser transmit the request, it won't know that this is javascript.